# automapper: skipping/ignoring nested types

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm trying to create a map between a domain object and viewmodel to support a use case that feels quite common. The fact that I can't find a solution makes me think I'm approaching the problem incorrectly.  Here's some psuedo code that represents my source and destination types:

```
public class DomainClass
    {
        public NestedDomainClass1 NestedDomainClass1{ get; set; }
    }

    public class NestedDomainClass1
    {
        public NestedDomainClass2 NestedDomainClass2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class NestedDomainClass2
    {
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
        public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    }


    public class DomainViewModel
    {
        public string PropertyA { get; set; }
        public string PropertyB { get; set; }
        public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, `DomainViewModel` maps perfectly to `DomainClass.NestedDomainClass1.NestedDomainClass2`.  However, for reasons that aren't entirely relevant, I can't simply create a mapping at that level. Instead I have to map two levels higher:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<DomainObj, DomainViewModel>();
```

This is unfortunate, as the minute I do this, I can no longer rely on AutoMapper conventions to automagically map similarly named properties, and I end having to write a lot of highly repetitive code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, DomainViewModel>().ForMember(dest=>dest.PropertyA, opt=>opt.MapFrom(source=>source.NestedDomainClass1.NestedDomainClass2.PropertyA));
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, DomainViewModel>().ForMember(dest=>dest.PropertyB, opt=>opt.MapFrom(source=>source.NestedDomainClass1.NestedDomainClass2.PropertyB));
```

I've played with the `RecognizeDestinationPrefixes` and `RecognizeDestinationPostfixes` methods in the hopes of getting AutoMapper to "skip" directly to the property I'd like to map from (`NestedDomainClass2`), but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're trying map between two completely different types. You really need to do something like this:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<NestedDomainClass2, DomainViewModel>();
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

var dvm = Mapper.Map<NestedDomainClass2, DomainViewModel>
                         (obj.NestedDomainClass1.NestedDomainClass2);
```

However if you want to, you can hide that detail by defining a `TypeConverter`. Something like this should work:

```cs
public class DomainTypeConverter : TypeConverter<DomainClass, DomainViewModel>
{
    protected override DomainViewModel ConvertCore(DomainClass source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<NestedDomainClass2, DomainViewModel>
                             (source.NestedDomainClass1.NestedDomainClass2);
    }
}
```

You can then define your mapping to be something like this:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<NestedDomainClass2, DomainViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, DomainViewModel>()
    .ConvertUsing(new DomainTypeConverter());
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

And use it like this:

```cs
var dvm = Mapper.Map<DomainClass, DomainViewModel>(dc);
```